# Custom action won't work?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, cms-block, admin-controller, action

My Customized controller seems not work. Added new method which suppose to update some values in table, here is my method:

```
    public function reorderAction()
    {
    Mage::log('=> test',true,'bannerposition.log',null);
    $bannerId = $this->getRequest()->getPost("id");
    $bannerNewOrder = $this->getRequest()->getPost("order");
    try {
            $model = Mage::getModel('cms/block');
            $model->load($bannerId);
            //$bannerOldPosition = $model->getPosition();
            $model->setPosition($bannerNewOrder);
            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('cms')->__( $block.' Updated.'));
            return 'Updated';

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            return 'Update Failed';
        }

    Mage::log('=> '.$result,true,'bannerposition.log',null);

    return $result;
    }
```

in ajax url:

```
    "admin/adminhtml/cms/block/reorder"
```

but I can't see anything, neither log created or change in database.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: write more that you have tried.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: add config xml where you register route.

Comment: I did not changed anything in config. Using core (local copy) BlockController.php where I added a new method. Should I register my new method to make it work ??

Comment: This way not working. Create a new module, overwrite BlockController, then should work. If you need help let me know.

Comment: I've changed saveAction this way, and everything works perfect so why this new method would not work ?

Comment: My new controller path (new custom module) is /app/code/local/Amber/SupaSlid/controllers, how should i add it into my module config ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89385/discussion-between-rob-d-a-and-sohel-rana).